# create additional users in mysql kubernetes pods

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I'm trying to create additional users for MySQL pod.

i used the env variable- `MYSQL_USER` to create additional users. after the creation of the pod. I'm able to only use the second user not the first user.

is there a way i can achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with
> the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided
> configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with
> extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in
> /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical
> order. You can easily populate your mysql services by mounting a SQL
> dump into that directory and provide custom images with contributed
> data. SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified
> by the MYSQL_DATABASE variable.

You can mount your files at that path

```
volumes:
      - ./<your-path-to-create-user.sql>:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

**create-user.sql**

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
CREATE USER 'user1'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
```

so after initializing the above SQL script will get executed and create the users to database,you can edit it as per need.

If you are on **Kubernetes** you can use the **configmap**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mysql
    image: mysql
    .....
    env:
    - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      value: "root"
    .....
    volumeMounts:
      - name: mysql-inituser
        mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  volumes:
  - name: mysql-inituser
    configMap:
      name: users
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: users
data:
  create-user.sql: |-
    CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
    CREATE USER 'user1'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
```

Comment: Manavar. thank you.


 since password is involved, i think we can use secrets in the place of configmaps. correct me if i'm wrong.

what is the procedure if the user wanted to change the password of his own. need to update the secret?? or any other suggestions

Comment: yes, definitely you can use secret. You can extend the above ref file with Hashi corp vault integration also if you are looking for more secure solution. shared just for basic ref.